# What is the most robust, universal ActiveRecord implementation for JavaScript/SSJS?

Tags: activerecord, serverside-javascript

Although I'm not very familiar with its usage yet, I'm intrigued by what I've seen of the power of convention-over-configuration employed in the ActiveRecord pattern, popularized by Ruby-on-Rails. I've seen a few JavaScript implementations out there, but was looking for advice on which was:

1. The most universal JavaScript implementation in terms of both adapter support (ranging from in-memory JSON stores to specific databases) and CommonJS-friendliness ([if relevant yet](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/RDBMS))
2. The most robust in terms of elegantly leveraging conventions for reducing redundancy and allowing for rapid application development.

Combining the strengths of JavaScript such as its possibilities for code reuse on the client and server-side, with what appears from my limited perspective to be the primary draw of RoR, seems a slam dunk.

Also any tips on getting started or good tutorials, would be most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is too late for this answer but you want to have a look at Ember and Ember-Data. Ember does exactly what you want. http://emberjs.com/